# Spyder regex multiline support?

Tags: regex, spyder, multiline

I cannot find the way to set the find/replace function to use multiline regular expressions in spite of this [github statement](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/717) (2015) from the program author:

> FYI I've just added support for multiline regular expressions. It's
> still exclusively on my local repository but I'll push the
> corresponding changeset to the online repository in the next hours.

How the UI looks like:

[image]

There is no options menu or button to select multiline, and the find/replace function is not described in the documentation as far as I know. Is it possible to use multiline regex with find/replace, or was multiline support never introduced?

Comment: Not sure about spyder, but you could try replacing your middle \s with [\s\r\n].  If it will scan past the newline at all this should match it.

Comment: @ChrisMaurer: That works and in my case is not a heavy workaround. Thanks!